# Insert multuple rows at once with a calculated column from prior inserts into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to do a multi-row insert as one statement in SQL Server, but where one of the columns is a column computer based on the data as it stands after every insert row.

Let's say I run this simple query and get back 3 records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_courses
WHERE event_id = 100
```

Results:

```
id | event_id | course_id | course_priority
---+----------+-----------+----------------
10 | 100      | 501       | 1
11 | 100      | 502       | 2
12 | 100      | 503       | 3
```

Now I want to insert 3 more records into this table, except I need to be able to calculate the priority for each record.  The priority should be the count of all courses in this event.  But if I run a sub-query, I get the same priority for all new courses:

```
INSERT INTO event_courses (event_id, course_id, course_priority)
VALUES (100, 500, 
           (SELECT COUNT (id) + 1 AS cnt_event_courses
            FROM event_courses
            WHERE event_id = 100)),
        (100, 501, 
            (SELECT COUNT (id) + 1 AS cnt_event_courses
             FROM event_courses
             WHERE event_id = 1))
```

Results:

```
id | event_id | course_id | course_priority
---+----------+-----------+-----------------
10 | 100      | 501       | 1
11 | 100      | 502       | 2
12 | 100      | 503       | 3
13 | 100      | 504       | 4
14 | 100      | 505       | 4
15 | 100      | 506       | 4
```

Now I know I could easily do this in a loop outside of SQL and just run a bunch of insert statement, but that's not very efficient. There's got to be a way to calculate the priority on the fly during a multi-row insert.

Big thanks to @Sean Lange for the answer.  I was able to simplify it even further for my application.  Great lead! Learned 2 new syntax tricks today ;)

```
DECLARE @eventid int = 100

INSERT event_courses
SELECT  @eventid AS event_id, 
        course_id, 
        course_priority = existingEventCourses.prioritySeed + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tempid)
FROM (VALUES 
    (1, 501), 
    (2, 502), 
    (3, 503)
) courseInserts (tempid, course_id) -- This basically creates a temp table in memory at run-time
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS prioritySeed
    FROM event_courses
    WHERE event_id = @eventid
) existingEventCourses

SELECT * 
FROM event_courses
WHERE event_id = @eventid
```

Comment: Look at ROW_NUMBER. It can do this for you quite easily.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use the ROW_NUMBER() inside an insert for multiple rows?  Or do I need to make a temporary table first and insert everything into it and then apply the row_number function to that and then update the main table?

Comment: Yes instead of a INSERT..VALUES(SUBSELECT) structure, you would do an INSERT..SELECT where the SELECT returns all the rows you want to insert at once, using ROW_NUMBER() for the Priority.   You don't need a temp table, but you might want to use a CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might be able to do this. I have no idea where your new rows values are coming from so I just tossed them in a derived table. I doubt your final solution would look like this but it demonstrates how you can leverage ROW_NUMBER for accomplish this type of thing.

```
declare @EventCourse table
(
    id int identity
    , event_id int
    , course_id int
    , course_priority int
)
insert @EventCourse values
(100, 501, 1)
,(100, 502, 2)
,(100, 503, 3)

select *
from @EventCourse


insert @EventCourse
(
    event_id
    , course_id
    , course_priority
)
select x.eventID
    , x.coursePriority
    , NewPriority = y.MaxPriority + ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by x.eventID order by x.coursePriority)
from 
(
    values(100, 504)
        ,(100, 505)
        ,(100, 506)
)x(eventID, coursePriority)
cross apply 
(
    select max(course_priority) as MaxPriority
    from @EventCourse ec
    where ec.event_id = x.eventID
) y

select *
from @EventCourse
```

Comment: Thank you, this totally helped, and I even learned 2 new syntax tricks from the example on top of it.

Comment: Glad that helped. :)